# Netbeans not recognizing JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I add a library that I've created to another Netbeans project, fix imports doesn't work.. even me writing the class path in the import doesn't work as well.

But when I compile it works like a charm.. but still in the netbeans project errors appear as class not found and package does not exist..

Any clue? :(

I use netbeans 7.4

Addition:
I removed the cache folder int he local folder and the problem just got worse.. more libraries are undefined now..

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. solved it by removing the configuration folder in the roaming folder and everything went fine afterwise..